# How to know if component is currently the loaded component in router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, eventemitter

I have an application with lazy loaded modules.

In one specific lazy loaded module, I have a parent component, which has `router-outlet`.

In that parent component I have a button which basically emit an event using a shared service (provided on the lazy loaded module).

each child component (which is loaded in `router-outlet`) is subscribing to that event using the same shared service!

I tried to recreate my use case in the following [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8lMlGwYZMHmMorItZG0) using *heroes demo*.

Open Dev tools to see `console` messages.

- Click on `Heroes` Link (it should be selected by default).
- Click on Hero Item from the list.
- Click on `Admin` Link.
- Click On `Emit Test` button (upper right nav)

You'll see -in the console- that Event was received by both components, even both components should not be '**Active**' !!!

1) Is this by design?

2) How to know if the current Component is the active one?

---

### SUMMARY/UPDATE

From my understanding, EventEmitter/Subject can be subscribed as many times, but when unsubscribed you cannot use it/subscribe to it AFAIK.

My solution was:

1) in service I ended doing the folowing:

```
get(){
  if (!this.testEvent.closed) {
      this.testEvent.complete();
      this.testEvent.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.testEvent= new EventEmitter<void>();
    return this.testEvent;
  }
}
```

2) In each component I subscribe to the event, I added ngDestroy and unsubscribed the event:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.testEvent.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here. There are many many files in your plunkr, and most are completely irrelevant, and you didn't tell which files to look at.

Comment: `app/heroes/hero-list.component.ts` and `app/heroes/hero-detail.component.ts`.

Comment: Which is the behaviour you would like the app to have?

Comment: @Picci, I guess when I do `event.emit()` then it should reach only **active** components, which are loaded on DOM!

Comment: @A.Akram your guess is wrong. RxJS doesn't know anything about angular, components and the DOM. And even if it did, the observable doesn't even know that the observer is a added from a component, and doesn't have a direct reference to the component.

Comment: My guess was when the child is removed from `router-outlet` (DOM) the Component instance should not exist anymore!

Comment: You're calling unsubscribe() on the testEvent, in the service. That doesn't make sense. The unsubscribe() must be called from the component, in the Subscription. Read the two answers you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a service, which is a singleton. This service exists from the beginning of the application until its end.

You have two components. These are not singletons. They are created when they must be displayed on a page, and destroyed when they must not be anymore.

And, when the components are created, you subscribe to an observable inside the singleton service. What does it mean? It means that the observable needs to keep a reference to your observer, which itself has an emplicit reference (this) to the component instance. Without that reference, the observable wouldn't be able to call the observer when an event is emitted. So, even though Angular doesn't need your component instance anymore, the observable still has a reference to it, and calls it when an event is emitted.

You thus need to unsubscribe when the component is not needed anymore:

```
private subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.service.getTestEvent().subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Without doing that, not only do you have observers called for nothing, making the app slower, but you also have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense...  I'll try it

Comment: Now, after `unsubscribe()` when I try to subscribe in another component I get an error `ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed`

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you never unsubscribe the event.
The more you click your users the more you will see lines in the console.
Any time you click you subscribe to the event, i.e. you add a callback that will get executed any time the event is raised, unless you unsubscribe.
In the method `ngOnDestroy()` you should call the `unsubscribe()` method on the subscription (which is the object returned by the `subscribe()` method).

In other words something like this

```
subscrition: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {

    this.subscription = this.service.getTestEvent().subscribe( (e) => {
      console.log('HeroListComponent ==>');
    });

.....

}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Now, after `unsubscribe()` when I try to subscribe in another component I get an error `ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed`

Comment: Hard to say anything without a **simple** example and reproducing scenario. But you shouldn't use an EventEmitter in a service. Use an RxJS Subject.

Comment: Using Subject, I'm getting the same error. The only solution I see it's returning new Subject/EventEmitter each time! I mean I cannot use the same Subject/EventEmitter after unsubscribing! it makes sense but I'm not sure!